# Is "that of" used in an appropriate way?

Tags: word-usage

Could you please tell me whether I use *that of* in an appropriate way or not?

> Here are the results of the
>   calculations. **That of** calculation
>   number four is pretty difficult to
>   get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case *that* is a demonstrative pronoun standing in for the phrase "the results of the calculation". So it is fine as it stands, except for one modification

> [The results of the calculation] of number four [are] pretty difficult to get.

Note that the number of the copula changes from singular to plural, *is* to *are*, since the antecedent (results) is plural.

Edit:

In the case I cited above, it is the copula that would change. In your case, splitting the thought over two sentences, the demonstrative pronoun that would change number as well:

> Here are the results of the calculations. Those of calculation number four are pretty hard to get.

This is only if number four would have "results" instead of "a result"; it's a minor point, but if you mean

> The result of calculation number four is pretty difficult to get.

then the singular "That of ... etc." would be fine. Whether or not there is a single *result* or multiple *results* for a single calculation is not clear from the example.

Comment: The sentence is false?

Comment: @Boob: I had a typo in my last sentence. "Not" should have been "note"; edited to reflect that. The sentence is essentially all right except for the issue with number agreement.

Comment: Why plural? that refers to **one** of four results, "one of them was/is pretty difficult".

Comment: @Boob: Meh, I was considering only the entire construction. Not the single-use case. In that case it is the pronoun that would change. Editing again, and getting coffee.

Comment: Life is short, enjoy your coffee. ;)

Answer (score 1):

"That of" used when you are saying which person or thing you are referring to:

> The voice was that of an elderly woman.

So, I think your sentence is correct.

Comment: @Marco: Was nothing.